# Java RegEx: can't figure out a solution

Tags: java, regex

I have a list of phone numbers that I need to filter using RegEx.

These should *not* match:

```
61-8434 0101
61 8434 0101
(11) 8434 0101
(11) 98434 0101
(47)84340101
(47) 984340101
4340502
3321-6769
33457899
21679541
2167-9547
846415
8875465
```

These should match:

```
99150 1000
67-9150-1000
67 91501000
67 991501000
(67) 991501000
(67) 99150-1000
(67) 9150-1000
(67) 9150 1000
(67) 99150 1000
```

I need that the RegEx do the following:

1. Select the numbers that follow the pattern: 8 or 9 digits that may or may not be divided by a hyphen sign or a space
2. Selection must start with 8 or 9
3. Selection may be preceded by 67/(67)/67-/67(space), but if preceded by any other number variations like: 61-/61 /11/(11)/47- then it should not be selected (In the example, the first 6 numbers in the list should not be selected)

I alredy managed to get items 1 and 2 done through the following RegEx:

```
[8-9]\d{3,4}[- ]?\d{4}
```

Output:
[RegEx Visual from http://www.ocpsoft.org](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q4uKK.jpg)

But I can't figure out how to accomplish item 3! Please help!

Comment: Just match all the possible starters and use anchors to avoid invalid ones, like [`^(?:(?:\(67\)|67)[- ]?)?[89](?:\d[- ]?){7,8}$`](https://regex101.com/r/uH7f37/1)

Comment: Consider keeping only the digit, then analyse them

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not exactly strict, but should work well for you:

```
^(\(?67\)?[ -]?)?[89]([ -]?\d){6,7}\d$
```

See [live demo](http://rubular.com/r/DiJw0NUzT0).

Comment: Why not allow space or dash between last two digits? Also, regex would allow `(67 991501000` and `67)-991501000`. I think regex should be `^(67[ -]?|\(67\) )?[89]([ -]?\d){7,8}$`. See [regex101](https://regex101.com/r/uDnhav/1).

Comment: @andreas as I said in my answer, it's not totally strict, but is good enough given that all input *could* be a number - as per the question, this is a *filtering* exercise, not an input *validation* exercise.

Comment: I have upvoted this answer given that it meets most requirements in the OP and should be easily extended if necessary.

Comment: Bohemian, can you explain how this ([ -]?\d){6,7} works? Why does it allow space or hyphen without counting it in the {6,7}? How does it allow hyphen and space anywhere between the {6,7} digit sequency?

Comment: @bankRupt The pattern `[ -]?\d`, i.e. a digit optionally prefixed by a separator, is repeated 6-7 times. The `{6,7}` quantifier pattern applies to the `(X)` capturing group pattern. As an improvement, since you're not interested in actually capturing the sub-pattern, the `(X)` capture group could be made non-capturing by writing it as `(?:X)`, i.e. `(?:[ -]?\d){6,7}`. Bohemian is just keeping it simple.

Comment: ty @Andreas, now I got it!